# Followup on parallel diode circuits

Tags: circuit-analysis, diodes

In another post, [Diode circuit with parallel voltage source](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/128045/diode-circuit-with-parallel-voltage-source), many of the top answers quickly claim that the voltage of interest in the circuit must be greater than 1 'by inspection'.

[image]

I'm very new to this and so I can't see how this is true. I tried to understand this by guessing the answer to be 2V, and then the top two diodes would be reverse biased, leaving only the bottom diode on. But I can't anything more from this and how this indicates a conflict.

Answer (score 2):

If the diodes are ideal -

- If only D1 exists then V = +3 V because current will flow through R1 and D1 to the +3 V point.
- If we add in D2 then, since V > +2 V current will flow through D2 so V will drop to +2 V.
- If we now add in D1 then, since V > +1 V current will flow through D1 so V will drop to +1 V.

> I tried to understand this by guessing the answer to be 2 V, and then the top two diodes would be reverse biased,

That might be a good starting point but soon you realise that if V = +2 V and D3 is connected to +1 V then it is forward biases, will conduct and pull V down to +1 V.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the circuit in question: -

[image]

Only one diode will "win" and that diode "wins" by conducting. The other diodes will "lose" because they become reverse biased. If I posed this circuit: -

[image]

And, I asked you what V was, would you be able to say that it was 3 volts without any doubts i.e. D1 "wins" because it is forward biased whereas D2 "loses" because with 3 volts at its cathode and 2 volts at its anode, it is reverse biased.

If you follow that then it should be no great leap to understand why in the first diagram, using ideal diodes, V = 1 volt.

Comment: In your example, how do you know that V is 3V? Why couldn't it be 2V. In that case, both diodes would be forward biased.

Comment: @AyumuKasugano Because it's an ideal diode. If it's forward-biased, it has no resistance -- so there's no way to maintain 3V at its anode and 2V at its cathode.

Comment: @AyumuKasugano only one diode can win. Both cannot be conducting unless they have exactly the same voltage on both their terminals and that then becomes trivial.